# How to generate named nodes from the counter used in `foreach` in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, loops

I'm trying to generate multiple nodes in TikZ using the `foreach` operator, but whatever I try I get compilation errors. I need all nodes to be named in order to draw edges between them.

Having read that `let` could solve it, here follows my latest attempt:

```
\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}
{
  \node let \n1 = (4+\i)
    in
      at +(1, 0) [process_small] (p0\n1) {};
}
```

Comment: Similar question: [tikz pgf - Pointing to a node with calculated name, why do I get to the east, not to the center? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161532/pointing-to-a-node-with-calculated-name-why-do-i-get-to-the-east-not-to-the-ce)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code isn't actually far off.  There are three errors in it.  Here's a corrected version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1, 2, 3}
{
  \path let \n1 = {int(4+\i)}
  in
  node at +(\n1, 0) [draw] (p0\n1) {};
}
\draw (p05) -- (p06) -- (p07);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The errors are:

1. A minor one this, you used parentheses to group your arithmetic when you should have used braces (at least for the outermost grouping).
2. The let operation can't come between a node and its arguments.  You have to have it beforehand.  Nodes are a bit special and examine the following text very carefully, so it's best not to make it too complicated.  In this case, it's possible to put the `let` before the node by writing `\path let ... node` instead of `\node let ...`.
3. The last mistake is a very common one: dots in node names.  Your syntax, when corrected as above, would assign the node names `p05.0`, `p06.0`, and `p07.0`.  These are fine as node names, but unusable as coordinates later because they match the `node.anchor` pattern so get interpreted as, say, 0 degrees on the boundary of node `p05` (which doesn't exist as it is called `p05.0`).  If using `\pgfmathsetmacro` directly, we'd use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to avoid this but as you're using a `let` we have to be a bit sneaky and put in an explicit `int`.

Comment: Using `let` just to get an integer is a little overkill. I would use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{int(4+\i)}` instead. Or is there any difference in the result?

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I don't know about the implementations, but I would guess that `let` uses pgfmath internally so they'd be pretty similar (note that in your example you don't need the `int`).  My intention was to show how the original code was not actually far from working - when I started writing it then Gonzalo's answer was still there.