# Pointing to a node with calculated name, why do I get to the east, not to the center?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgfmath

It seems like I'm doing something wrong when using `foreach` variables to indicate node numbers. The two foreach loops are anchoring the paths to the east of each node. Why does this happen?

[image: example output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,fit,patterns,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  labelnode/.style={draw=none, fill=none, black},
  latentnode/.style={draw, minimum width=5mm, shape=circle, ultra thick, black},
  dagconn/.style={arrows=->, black, thick},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\colgap}{1.6}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\rowgap}{1.3}

 \node[labelnode] (x1) at (\colgap*0,\rowgap*1) {$X_1$};
 \node[labelnode] (x2) at (\colgap*1,\rowgap*1) {$X_2$};
 \node[labelnode] (x3) at (\colgap*2,\rowgap*1) {$X_3$};

 \node[latentnode,blue] (x4) at (\colgap*0,\rowgap*0) {$X_4$};
 \node[latentnode,red] (x5) at (\colgap*1,\rowgap*0) {$X_5$};
 \node[labelnode] (x6) at (\colgap*2,\rowgap*0) {$X_6$};

 \foreach \c in {1,...,2} {
   \foreach \r in {1,...,2} {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{(((\r-1)*3)+\c)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\en}{\st+1}
     \draw[dagconn] ([xshift=0.2cm]x\st) to ([xshift=-0.9cm]x\en);
   }
 }

 \foreach \c in {1,...,3} {
   \foreach \r in {1,...,1} {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{((\r-1)*3)+\c}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\en}{\st+3}
     \draw[dagconn] (x\st) to (x\en);
   }
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`

Comment: Yes, changing `\pgfmathsetmacro` to `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` fixes the problem. Thanks @percusse.

Answer (score 7):

To not let the question unanswered, I explain why the east anchor was used and why @percusse recommended to use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`.

By `\pgfmathsetmacro{\st}{((\r-1)*3)+\c}` you will get decimal values such as 1.0, 2.0 and 3.0. So your node names `x\st` will become `x1.0`, `x2.0` and `x3.0`. Incidentally, those names are allowed, since that's the syntax for a so called *border anchor*. The expression after the dot is working as an angle given in degrees. That's why `x1.0` is actually the same as `x1.east`. `x1.90` would have been like `x1.north`.

So you need to get rid of the decimal point, which can be done by using `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` instead of `\pgfmathsetmacro`:

```
\foreach \c in {1,...,3} {
  \foreach \r in {1,...,1} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\st}{((\r-1)*3)+\c}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\en}{\st+3}
    \draw[dagconn] (x\st) to (x\en) node{\st};
  }
}
```