# Draw uniform lines/grid on a distorted square/axes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates

[image: Uniform grid on distorted axes]

I want to draw a square discretised by equally spaced lines. However, if I move one of the nodes, say node 4, the grid lines will keep it's relative spacing (see the image). I have no idea what to search for. One idea would be to calculate coordinates on the path (1)--(4) and (4)--(3), then re-calculate the coordinates when ever I move node 4 before I draw lines between the two opposite sides. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Many thanks.

Comment: Assuming you are using tikz, then \foreach\x={0,1,2,...,8}{\draw ($(1)!{\x/8}!(4)$) -- ($(2)!{\x/8}!(3)$);} or something like that.

Comment: Welcome! Please post the code you have, even if it is for just the non-distorted square. It is easier to help you if we start from the point where you get stuck.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sounds like an answer, doesn't it? ;)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. Yes, I'm using tikz. Currently trying to understand the bit in between the two dollar signs. Thank you all so much for replying.

@cfr: I will definitely do next time. Sorry, it's my first time posting and using this place, I didn't think I should post my obviously less efficient attempts.

Comment: @RaymonWhite If you want, I finally improved the code to draw the grid automatically!

Comment: Wow, that's so awesome! Thank you so much. I'm new to stackexchange, how can I thank you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my attempt. Initially I started looking for a solution similar to the one proposed by John Kormylo in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270014/draw-uniform-lines-grid-on-a-distorted-square-axes/270045#comment648169_270014), and ended up using the `decorations.markings` library. I hope it is not such an overkill :-) ! In every case the grid is self-adapting, as you can see from the following images:

[image][image][image]    [image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\def\NrLines{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\UnitSegment}{1/(\NrLines+1)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=red]

% Nodes definition
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=below:1] (a) at (2,5) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=below:2] (b) at (5,1) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=above:3] (c) at (6,2) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=above:4] (d) at (5,3) {};

% Paths between nodes
\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (a) -- (b);

\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-2-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (b) -- (c);

\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-3-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (c) -- (d);

\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-4-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (d) -- (a);

% Grid
\draw (mark-1-2) -- (mark-3-9);
\draw (mark-1-3) -- (mark-3-8);
\draw (mark-1-4) -- (mark-3-7);
\draw (mark-1-5) -- (mark-3-6);
\draw (mark-1-6) -- (mark-3-5);
\draw (mark-1-7) -- (mark-3-4);
\draw (mark-1-8) -- (mark-3-3);
\draw (mark-1-9) -- (mark-3-2);

\draw (mark-2-2) -- (mark-4-9);
\draw (mark-2-3) -- (mark-4-8);
\draw (mark-2-4) -- (mark-4-7);
\draw (mark-2-5) -- (mark-4-6);
\draw (mark-2-6) -- (mark-4-5);
\draw (mark-2-7) -- (mark-4-4);
\draw (mark-2-8) -- (mark-4-3);
\draw (mark-2-9) -- (mark-4-2);

% Nodes circles
\foreach \a in {a,...,d}{%
    \fill[black] (\a) circle (2pt);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In this code `\NrLines` is defined as the number of internal lines, which are separated by a distance equal to `\UnitSegment`.

Unfortunately I could not find a way to draw the grid automatically; I tried with:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{\NrLines+1}

\foreach \x in {1,2}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\x+2}
    \foreach \i/\j in {2/\End,...,\End/2}{%
        \draw (mark-\x-\i) -- (mark-\y-\j);
    }
}
```

but there was a problem with using the result of `\pgfsetmacro{}` inside a node name. Maybe someone more expert than me may suggest a solution to use this `\foreach` loop.

**EDIT:** Finally, I improved the code to draw the grid automatically! There were two issues:

- the use of `\pgfmathsetmacro` inside a node name, solved thanks to Stefan Kottwitz's answer "[Pointing to a node with calculated name, why do I get to the east, not to the center?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161532/pointing-to-a-node-with-calculated-name-why-do-i-get-to-the-east-not-to-the-ce)": instead of `pgfmathsetmacro`, one should use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to remove decimal points in the result;
- the internal `\foreach` loop can not work using `\foreach \i/\j in {2/\End,...,\End/2}` since it is not clear (for the solver :-) ) how `\i` and `\j` are changing. Therefore, `\j` is evaluated in each step as a function of `\i`, which is the only counter for the loop.

The new improved code is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\def\NrLines{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\UnitSegment}{1/(\NrLines+1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\End}{\NrLines+1}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=red]

% Nodes definition
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=below:1] (a) at (2,0) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=below:2] (b) at (5,0) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=above:3] (c) at (4,3) {};
\node[inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,label=above:4] (d) at (3,3) {};

% Paths between nodes
\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (a) -- (b);

\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-2-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (b) -- (c);

\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-3-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (c) -- (d);

\draw [postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,
mark=between positions 0 and 1 step \UnitSegment with {
\node [inner sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt,
name=mark-4-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
{};}}] (d) -- (a);

% Grid
\foreach \x in {1,2}{%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\y}{\x+2}
    \foreach \i in {2,...,\End}{%
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\j}{\End-\i+2}
        \draw (mark-\x-\i) -- (mark-\y-\j);
    }
}

% Nodes circles
\foreach \a in {a,...,d}{%
    \fill[black] (\a) circle (2pt);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now you can easily modify the grid setting the number of internal lines `\NrLines`, and the code will work without problems!

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was hoping to do! Working from your example, I'm now trying to add an extra node at the centroid and make the grid move with that (whilst keeping all other nodes still). I have no idea how hard this would be.

Comment: @RaymonWhite you're welcome! If you have some question about my solution, feel free to ask! I'm not sure of what you mean with "make the grid move with the centroid". If it is worth it, you could open a follow up question.

Comment: Hi, thank you for improving the code! I'll look at it later on tonight.
By "centroid" I mean, to place a node right in the middle of the square (the centoid), or on a mid-edge (say between node 1 and node 2).

Then imagine if I were to drag that new node around and keep all other nodes fixed. The grid will distort accordingly.

For now, in my thesis, I've just described the effects in words, not attempted to draw it yet. I want to get this thesis finished, I'll come back to it when I have time at the end.

Comment: @RaymonWhite you're welcome! I think that for the centroid it is worth opening a new question, since it seems not so trivial :-) !

Answer (score 10):

Here's one better way, using [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), using the `point x of y` notation.  TikZ has the same idea, but using a rather more compact notation.  With this set up you can move your four points as much as you like, and the grid will adapt itself accordingly.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

z1 = origin;
z2 = (80,0);
z3 = (96,80);
z4 = (-10,40);

n = 8;

for i=0 upto n:
  draw point i/n of (z1--z2) -- point i/n of (z4--z3) withcolor .67 red;
  draw point i/n of (z1--z4) -- point i/n of (z2--z3) withcolor .67 red;
endfor

dotlabel.llft("1", z1);
dotlabel.lrt ("2", z2);
dotlabel.urt ("3", z3);
dotlabel.ulft("4", z4);

endfig;
end.
```

Now I've moved `z3` and `z4` a bit, but changed nothing else.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Thruston for the reply. I've not heard of  Metapost before. I'll look into it as soon as I'm done with this report. The solution you've provided really does look elegant compared to my initial solution in tikz.

Answer (score 7):

A generalisation of John Kormylo's comment above, all tied up in `pic`.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
grid/.style args={(#1)#2(#3)#4(#5)#6(#7)#8}{code={%
\tikzset{pics/grid/dimensions=#8}%
\foreach \i in {0,...,\y}
  \draw [pic actions/.try] ($(#1)!\i/\y!(#7)$) -- ($(#3)!\i/\y!(#5)$);
\foreach \i in {0,...,\x}
  \draw [pic actions/.try] ($(#1)!\i/\x!(#3)$) -- ($(#7)!\i/\x!(#5)$);
\path (#1) coordinate (-1) (#3) coordinate (-2)
      (#5) coordinate (-3) (#7) coordinate (-4);
}},
grid/dimensions/.code args={#1x#2}{\def\x{#1}\def\y{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic (A) at (0,0) [black] {grid={(0,0) (4,0)  (4,4) (0,4)  8x8}};
\pic (B) at (7,0) [red]   {grid={(0,0) (4,0)  (4,3) (0,5)  8x8}};
\pic (C) at (0,7) [green] {grid={(0,0) (4,0)  (5,5) (0,3)  8x8}};
\pic (D) at (7,7) [blue]  {grid={(0,0) (3,-1) (4,5) (-1,3) 8x8}};
\foreach \i in {A,...,D}
  \foreach \j in {1,...,4}
    \fill (\i-\j) circle [radius=.1] node [anchor=\j*90-45] {\j};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]